# Nuxt js Client specific layout loading

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am using nuxtjs to set custom theme on the basis of a specific value (eg:token,client_id etc)
What I am facing, in nuxt layout context can't find the vuex.$store values. what can be done?

example code:

```
layout(ctx) {
      console.log(ctx.theme_val)
      return this.$store.state.theme_val == 2 ? 'bg1' : 'bg2'

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get store from a [context](https://nuxtjs.org/api/context/).

```
layout(ctx) {
   return ctx.store.state.theme_val == 2 ? 'bg1' : 'bg2'
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Today I have reached to max upvote limit. I'll up u next day.
thanks